# BindValue Loop in insert wih pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my table 'config' I have 38 fields, As you can see below:

[image]

Then, instead of typing all these fields at the time I think to insert the following code :

```
$var = "";// var para os campos
$var0 = ""; // var para os values

for($i=1;$i<39;$i++){
    $var = $var.$i.',';
}

for($i=0;$i<36;$i++){
    $var0 = $var0.':'.$i.',';
}


$info_config = $ponte_db->prepare('INSERT INTO config ('.$var.') VALUES ('.$valor_cout.','.$var0.') ');    

for($i=0;$i<36;$i++){
    $info_config->bindValue(":".$i, $result[$i]);
}

$info_config->execute();
```

The variable result is as follows

[image]

So, my idea doesn't work but the results in DataBase don't save, why?

Comment: Your table `config` is written with or without a 's' like this `configs` ?

Comment: Sorry, my table name is config, i edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a little problem, your string is rewrite every time:

so instead of this:

```
for($i=1;$i<39;$i++){
   $var = $var.$i.',';
}

for($i=0;$i<36;$i++){
   $var0 = $var0.':'.$i.',';
}
```

Do this:

```
for($i=1;$i<39;$i++){
   $var .= $var.$i.',';
}

for($i=0;$i<36;$i++){
   $var0 .= $var0.':'.$i.',';
}
```

The only difference is that I add a `.` to the `=`.

`.=` is a short hand for `$string = $string + 'value';`

Also I think you should change this (but I am not sure because I don't know where the `$valor_cout` comes from):

```
$info_config = $ponte_db->prepare('INSERT INTO config ('.$var.') VALUES ('.$valor_cout.','.$var0.') ');
```

To

```
$info_config = $ponte_db->prepare('INSERT INTO config ('.$var.') VALUES ('.$var0.') ');
```

Comment: $valor_cout is a $_cookie and represents the login of the user